# Test whether words of less a's than b's or c's but not at the same time is context-free

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I want to test whether $L= \{w\in\{a,b,c\}^* \mid |w|_a<|w|_b \text{ or } |w|_a<|w|_c,\text{ but not at the same time} \}$ is CFL or not (I assume not), but I am struggling to do so.

The closest I have been to prove that it isn't a CFL is by seeing that the languages $L_1=\{a^nb^{n+1}c^n\mid n\ge0 \}$ and $L_2=\{a^nb^nc^{n+1}\mid n\ge0 \}$, for example, are contained within it and are obviously not context-free, but that doesn't prove anything.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you have identified a tip!

Let me make it more explicit. Suppose $L$ is context-free and $p>0$ is a pumping length for it as in the pumping lemma for context-free language. Try pumping up or down the word $a^pb^{p+1}c^p$ out of $L$.

(You can also pump up or down the word $a^pb^pc^{p+1}$ out of $L$.)

Comment: Oh, should the pumping lemma for CFLs be used here? I was actually avoiding that since it was part of a series of recommended problems before showing the pumping lemma, so I suspect this may be solved with CFL closure properties and such

Comment: I doubt this could be solved without the pumping lemma.  The CFL closure properties are not very powerful since CFLs are not closed under intersection nor under union.

Comment: That's true. Thank you very much, irregardless!